# Averaging every n columns Inner Join for Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I am having trouble figuring how to average 10 columns in the following scenario:

I have two tables

```
--------------------
|Name|ClosestSiteID|
|AAA |001          |
|BBB |002          |
--------------------
```

And the second table

```
-----------------------
|SiteID|DateTime|Value|
|001   |0       |10   |
|001   |1       |20   |
|001   |2       |20   |
|001   |3       |10   |
|002   |0       |5    |
|002   |1       |15   |
-----------------------
```

... etc with hundreds of entries for every SiteID

I want to write a join between these two tables, on SiteID that averages every 10 entries in site ID so that the output looks something like this

```
-------------------------------------
|Name  |ClosestSiteID|DateTime|Value|
|AAA   |001          |0       |AVG  |
|AAA   |001          |10      |AVG  |
|BBB   |002          |0       |AVG  |
|BBB   |002          |10      |AVG  |
-------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do this in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  Add a sequential number to `table2` for each `SiteId`.  Then divide this number by `10` and use the result for aggregation purposes:

```
select t1.name, t1.ClosestSiteId, min(DateTime) as DateTime,
       avg(value) as value
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by SiteId order by date) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     )
     on t1.ClosestSiteId = t2.SiteId;
group by t1.name, t1.ClosestSiteId, (seqnum - 1) / 10
order by name, ClosestSideId, DateTime;
```